# Copy/Sync changed data alone from one database to another in specific interval, Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have a requirement where I need to capture the changes in one Postgres server and make the same updates to another database in another server after specific intervals.

So what I want is both databases to be in **sync** during an interval that I specify.

I don't want to take a the whole Database dump, only the changes that occurred after last sync needs to be updated.

What are the ways this can be achieved? If it is possible.

Comment: You can use streaming replication with a delay

Comment: Can you give details or provide a link for reference @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Also will this work while using Amazon RDS ? @a_horse_with_no_name